# How to find figure captions in a PDF?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, figure

I want to develop a Python script that can find all of the figure captions within a PDF. I was wondering if it is possible to gather all the figure captions and append them to an array as it is searching for new figure captions.

I have tried searching for the word "Figure" and then grabbing the entire sentence that is present within it, but it is not efficient because it wouldn't find all of the sentences within the caption, and instead, only the sentence that is separated with a period.

**EDIT**
The following is a sample PDF that I intend to be working with. As you see, the word Fig.1 is written right below the image.
[image]

**NEW EDIT**
Here is the full HTML file that was converted with pdf2htmlEX:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hYriVrTlwmxR35A2Jy7mKoO4ns2oWe3Z

Comment: Hello Ishan. Could you please link to an example pdf, or if that's not possible post an example of the figure caption and surrounding text. Also a code sample of what you have so far would be helpful.

Comment: @Researcher Hi, I have updated the post with a sample PDF. I do not have any sample code yet because I do not know the correct method to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you try running the text extract using pypdf2 below? Sometimes this doesn't work, but hopefully you will be lucky with your pdf. Once you've done that, post what you get, probably shouldn't be too hard to search for separators between captions and the rest of the text.

Comment: If this doesn't work, next thing I would try is to convert it to html and use beautifulsoup4 to hunt down the captions.

Comment: @Researcher Yes, I have used PyPDF2 in the past, but the issue with extracting all of the text is that it will not find the word "Figure" that pertains only to the figure caption. For example, "figure" could be written in other places in the PDF as well, so simply searching for the word "figure" is not very ideal.

Also, the PDF reader returns all of the text, but it has errors with spacing, formatting, and some of the words are byte buffers.

Comment: I was hoping it would extract "Fig. x. --" and you could use regex to search for this. Then search for double line break afterwards. Looks like converting to html is probably best.

Comment: Can you give this a try? https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX

Comment: Run the pdf through that and post the html.

Comment: @Researcher Thanks for the comment. I have used pdf2htmlEX to convert the sample PDF to HTML. I have put a shareable Google Drive link with the file, please check it out.

Comment: Haha so that was awful. But trial and error will get us there eventually.

Comment: Best I have so far is pdfminer.six. See text output below. This comes from using pdf2text.py.

Comment: So even this is not going to be fully automated as the base text has some inconsistency. Figure 2 is "Fig, 2". whereas figure 1 is "Fig. 1.". Also I noticed a bug around Fig.4 output, it has "Fig. 3." thrown in. Maybe a job for mechanical turk... How many documents do you want to process?

Comment: Is your pdf tagged?

Comment: @Researcher I am processing one PDF at a time. I have just tried pdfminer.six, and it was much better because it showed spaces and the words correctly, just like how you have shown below. What do you think would be best to find "Figure" as it could be written as "Fig" as well.

Comment: I have added some code to the answer which gets close to what you're after. Unfortunately pdfminer.six produces a few inconsistencies as I said. I have also tried converting the pdf to image and running it through tesseract. This produces easy to process blocks of text but has the problem of making a few mistakes on letters.

Comment: I think you will still be looking at some manual steps any way you try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is not complete, will update it as we go through the problem.

Copy of original PDF:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC335638/pdf/pnas00677-0355.pdf

**Step 1 - Try pypdf**

```
# importing required modules 
import PyPDF2 

# creating a pdf file object 
pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf', 'rb') 

# creating a pdf reader object 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 

# printing number of pages in pdf file 
print(pdfReader.numPages) 

# creating a page object 
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0) 

# extracting text from page 
print(pageObj.extractText()) 

# closing the pdf file object 
pdfFileObj.close()
```

This wasn't suitable as even the words weren't separated by spaces.

**Step 2 - try pdf2htmlEX**

Suggested we try https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX to convert to html and then develop appropriate selectors to use with beautifulsoup4.

pdf2htmlex produced html where every single word was surrounded by tags and didn't help us at all.

**Step 3 - try pdfminer.six**

https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six

This is much better, though still not perfect:

> CIRCUITS IN THE CEREBELLAR CONTROL OF MOVEMENT
>
> BY JOHN C. ECCLES
>
> AMA/ERF INSTITUTE FOR BIOMEDICAL RESEARCH, CHICAGO
>
> Communicated May 16, 1967
>
> Neuroanatomists have generally recognized that the cerebellum provides
>   the greatest challenge in our initial efforts to discern functional
>   meaning in neuronal patterns because there is a stereotyped and simple
>   geometrical arrangement of its Presumably, it is for this reason that
>   there is the unique neuronal constituents. most refined knowledge of
>   microstructure that is available in the central nervous system. The
>   pioneer investigations of Ram6n y Cajall have led in recent times to
>   fascinating developments concerning microstructure, geometrical
>   arrangements, and numerical assessment.2
>
> As shown in Figure 1,3 there are only two kinds of afferent fibers
>   conveying information to the cerebellum, the climbing fibers (cf) and
>   the mossy fibers (mf); and there is only one type of efferent fiber
>   from the cerebellum, the axons of the Purkinje cells (Pc), which
>   terminate in the cerebellar nuclei (cn) and otherwise largely in
>   Deiters' nucleus. The climbing fiber is uniquely distributed to a
>   single
>
> FIG. 1.-Perspective drawing by Fox3 of a part of a folium of the
>   cerebellar cortex. The principal
>
> components are shown in diagrammatic form, and are described in the
>   text.
>
> 336
>
> VOL. 58, 1967
>
> PHYSIOLOGY: J. C. ECCLES
>
> 337

We can then run this code on the output:

```
import re

# Read In Text
fileName = "sample.txt"
pdfTextfile = open(fileName, "r")
pdfText = pdfTextfile.read()

# Split text into blocks separated by double line break.
blocks = pdfText.split("\n\n")

# Remove all new lines within blocks to remove arbitary line breaks
blocks = map(lambda x : x.replace("\n", ""), blocks)

# Which blocks are figure captions?
captions = []
for block in blocks:
    if re.search('^fig', block, re.IGNORECASE):
        captions.append(block)

# Done!
for caption in captions:
    print(caption)
    print()
```

This may need some more tweaking, as the output of pdfminer.six is not quite perfect.

**Step 4 - Try Tesseract**

I was curious to see how good OCR would be in this case. First convert the pdf to images. Then install the following:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
pip install pyocr
```

This code will perform OCR on the image.

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

import pyocr
import pyocr.builders

tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
if len(tools) == 0:
    print("No OCR tool found")
    sys.exit(1)

tool = tools[0]
print("Will use tool '%s'" % (tool.get_name()))

langs = tool.get_available_languages()
print("Available languages: %s" % ", ".join(langs))
lang = langs[0]
print("Will use lang '%s'" % (lang))

imageFile = "page_1.jpg"

txt = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open(imageFile),
    lang=lang,
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
)
open("page_1.txt","w").write(txt)
```

This produces better blocks of text, but has a few typos:

> CIRCUITS IN THE CEREBELLAR CONTROL OF MOVEMENT
>
> By Joun C. Eccuss
>
> AMA/ ERF INSTITUTE FOR BIOMEDICAL RESEARCH, CHICAGO
>
> Communicated May 16, 1967
>
> Neuroanatomists have generally recognized that the cerebellum provides
>   the greatest challenge in our initial efforts to discern functional
>   meaning in neuronal patterns because there is a stereotyped and simple
>   geometrical arrangement of its unique neuronal constituents.
>   Presumably, it is for this reason that there is the most refined
>   knowledge of microstructure that is available in the central nervous
>   system. The pioneer investigations of Ram6n y Cajal! have led in
>   recent times to fascinating developments concerning microstructure,
>   geometrical arrangements, and numerical assessment.’
>
> As shown in Figure 1,* there are only two kinds of afferent fibers
>   conveying information to the cerebellum, the climbing fibers (cf) and
>   the mossy fibers (m/f); and there is only one type of efferent fiber
>   from the cerebellum, the axons of the Purkinje cells (Pc), which
>   terminate in the cerebellar nuclei (en) and otherwise largely in
>   Deiters’ nucleus. The climbing fiber is uniquely distributed to a
>   single
>
> Fic. 1.—Perspective drawing by Fox? of a part of a folium of the
>   cerebellar cortex. The principal components are shown in diagrammatic
>   form, and are described in the text.
>
> 336

Comment: how do I download the pyocr tools?